# How can I filter UITableView with two predicates in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have tableView with `searchDisplayController`. In this TV i have to arrays (first/last names)
I can filter this values by names, using predicate, with this code

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.firstName beginswith[cd]%@",searchString];
self.filteredAllClients = [AllClients filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Can i filter this arrays using two predicates?

**For example:** I have names (Jack Stone, Mike Rango)

1. If I`m entering 'J' and i should get filtered array - Jack Stone
2. But if I'm  entering 'R' and i should get filtered area - Mike Rango?

Comment: Is there any problem with using `OR`/`AND` for several conditions ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, like this...

```
NSPredicate *firstNamePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.firstName beginswith[cd]%@",searchString];
NSPredicate *lastNamePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.lastName beginswith[cd]%@",searchString];

NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[firstNamePredicate, lastNamePredicate]];

self.filteredAllClients = [AllClients filteredArrayUsingPredicate:compoundPredciate];
```

This will then show all people whose first names begin with the search OR whose last names begin with the search.

I prefer using this format to using the ORs and ANDs in a single predicate as it makes the overall code more readable.

This can also be used to get the NOT of a predicate.

You can also easily get confused if you have compound predicates built in a single predicate.